# Using primarily BigQuery but also using images

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I'm on GCP and going to save structured data in BigQuery.  There are multiple images associated to each record.

What do you recommend for image storage when pairing with BigQuery?  I'm comfortable with BQ, but should I look at another database alternative?

Comment: Answers will be opinion-based since the complete use-case is not clear but here are your options to let you decide --> https://cloud.google.com/products/databases/
https://cloud.google.com/products/storage/

Comment: Thanks!  That linked helped!